# std::ranges::any_of fails when compiling with Apple Clang 14.0

Tags: c++, c++20, apple-clang

When I compile my program I get this error: `error: no member named 'any_of' in namespace 'std::ranges'`. However, I do include all the necessary headers (e.g. algorithm). I use c++20 standard and my compiler version is Apple Clang 14.0. Why do I get this error? I highly appreciate it if someone is able to explain to me the root cause of this.

I tried to go through if there are some issues with the library and my compiler, but could not get an affirmative answer from here either: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features

I first tried to implement this on my own code when I got the error. However, I get the same errors when running the example code from cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of

Below is the example code I was trying to run (copied from the previous link).

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
 
namespace ranges = std::ranges;
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10, 2);
    std::partial_sum(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), v.begin());
    std::cout << "Among the numbers: ";
    ranges::copy(v, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    if (ranges::all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; })) {
        std::cout << "All numbers are even\n";
    }
    if (ranges::none_of(v, std::bind(std::modulus<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, 2))) {
        std::cout << "None of them are odd\n";
    }
 
    auto DivisibleBy = [](int d)
    {
        return [d](int m) { return m % d == 0; };
    };
 
    if (ranges::any_of(v, DivisibleBy(7))) {
        std::cout << "At least one number is divisible by 7\n";
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
Among the numbers: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
All numbers are even
None of them are odd
At least one number is divisible by 7
```

The output my compiler gives me

```
src/day04.cpp:16:13: error: no member named 'copy' in namespace 'std::ranges'
    ranges::copy(v, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    ~~~~~~~~^
src/day04.cpp:19:9: error: no member named 'all_of' in namespace 'std::ranges'; did you mean 'std::all_of'?
    if (ranges::all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }))
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        std::all_of
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/all_of.h:26:1: note: 'std::all_of' declared here
all_of(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred) {
^
src/day04.cpp:23:17: error: no member named 'none_of' in namespace 'std::ranges'
    if (ranges::none_of(
        ~~~~~~~~^
src/day04.cpp:31:17: error: no member named 'any_of' in namespace 'std::ranges'
    if (ranges::any_of(v, DivisibleBy(7)))
        ~~~~~~~~^
4 errors generated.


        ~~~~~~~~^
```

I tried to include the `ranges` header in the code `#include<ranges>`, but got the same errors.

Comment: from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of

Comment: Are you sure you passed C++20 in the compiler flags? Clang won't use it by default yet.

Comment: Yes, this is my build command: `clang++ -g -Wall -std=c++20 main.cpp -o out/main` .

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/xT7T53fna

Comment: It seems that Apple Clang 14.0 does not yet support the std::ranges library. The std::ranges library was added in C++20, but not all compilers and standard libraries have implemented all C++20 features yet.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it is absolutely valid C++, it's just a namespace alias (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range version of the `<algorithm>` library has not been implemented in Apple Clang 14.0. You can check this by going through [each versions of Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes), or by going through the library files.

Range version of the `<algorithm>` library has been added to their [most recent stable branch of LLVM](https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/tree/apple/stable/20221013) however, so you can build it yourself if you need it right now(or just wait for future releases). Alternatively, you can install third party compilers like GCC or Clang.